# Python SDK v2 for Azure Machine Learning SDK (preview) - how to retrieve workspace from WorkspaceOperations

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I’m following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-python-sdk) to create ML pipelines with the new SDK.

So I started by loading the first class

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
```

and then I used it to authenticated on my workspace

```
ml_client = MLClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
    resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
    workspace_name=" mmAmlsWksp01",
)
```

However, I can’t understand how I can retrieve the objects it refers to. For example, it contains a “workspaces” member, but if I run

```
ml_client.workspaces["mmAmlsWksp01"]
```

, I get the error “***'WorkspaceOperations' object is not subscriptable***”.

So I tried to run

```
for w in ml_client.workspaces.list():
    print(w)
```

and it returns the workspace details (name, displayName, id…) for a SINGLE workspace, but not the workspace object.

In fact, the ml_client.workspaces object is a

<azure.ai.ml._operations.workspace_operations.WorkspaceOperations at 0x7f3526e45d60>

, but I don’t want a WorkspaceOperation, I want the Workspace itself. How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the get method on workspaces e.g.

> ml_client.workspaces.get.("mmAmlsWksp01")